# When was the potato introduced to Mexico?

Tags: food, mexico, agriculture, age-of-sail

There are wild potatoes in Mexico, but eating potatoes are generally cultivars imported from the Andes. They became popular elsewhere after Europeans with sailing ships took them around the world. Today they are readily available in Mexico, and on my last visit I was served a slice of raw potato on top of sushi.

The article "La papa: Apuntes sobre sus orígenes y su domesticación" says that the article "The domestication of roots and tubers in the American tropics" says that potatoes arrived in Mexico subsequent to Europeans, in 1519. According to [fao.org](http://www.fao.org/potato-2008/en/world/latinamerica.html#mexico), "some evidence suggests cultivated varieties were brought [to Mexico] by Spanish conquerors during the 1500s." The book "Strangers on Familiar Soil" describes La Pérouse bringing potatoes from Chile to California in 1786.

What does the evidence show? Is there a date by which Andean potatoes were definitely present in Mexico?

Comment: Are you after the date when they were first available to buy in Mexico or the date when they were first cultivated in Mexico?

Comment: See https://research.cip.cgiar.org/confluence/display/wpa/Mexico

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:** What does the evidence show? Is there a date by which Andean potatoes were definitely present in Mexico?

No because Mexico is within the area of origin of the Andean potato.
While there is no record of it being cultivated in Mexico until it was reintroduced by Europeans,  wild Andean potato's actually originated in that part of the world including in Mexico.

> **[Fun Facts about the Potato](https://www.potatogoodness.com/potato-fun-facts-history/)**
>   The Inca Indians in Peru were the first to cultivate potatoes around 8,000 BC to 5,000 B.C. In 1536 Spanish Conquistadors conquered Peru, discovered the flavors of the potato, and carried them to Europe.

.

> **[Potato Facts, from International Year of the Potato 2008](http://www.fao.org/potato-2008/en/world/latinamerica.html)**
>   The presence of wild potato plants in Mexico indicates that it lies within the potato's area of origin. However, some evidence suggests cultivated varieties were brought there by Spanish conquerors during the 1500s.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but it only alludes to the evidence I hope to see.